# Перед and затем : which cases are these?

Tags: грамматика

In this sentence:
Перед обязанности затем удовольствия
can you tell me in which cases are duty (dative, genitive, prepositional?) and pleasure (genitive? plural?)?
can you help me?
thanks

Comment: Maybe the right variant is - Передал обязанности затем удовольствия

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is incorrect even excluding cases of **обязанности** and **удовольствия** issue. And the answer depends on what do you really mean.
If the sentence supposed to be

> **"сначала обязанности, а потом удовольствия"**

then it can be helpful to insert skipped verbs here:

> **"сначала [идут] обязанности, а затем [идут] удовольствия"**

In this case, it's easier to see that the case is nominative.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence sounds strange. Better would `Сначала обязанности, затем удовольствия` or `Вперёд обязанности, потом удовольствия`

When I think on cases it's difficult for me to distinguish (perhaps someone will correct me here). Both would be either Nominative or Accusative.

I should also mention the Russian sayings/proverbs, that suit better here and mean the same thing you'd like to express:

`Сделал дело - гуляй смело` and `Делу время, потехе час`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be the first letter missing in the beginning of the phrase.

The most natural form would be, putting the lexical compatability aside, *Вперёд обязанности, затем - удовольствия.*

The cases in each part of the phrase are nominative.